# OpenLayers 4 ol.interaction.Modify - how delete last 2 points of Linestring or capture delete operation?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vertex

It is possible to capture delete event of vertex in OpenLayers?
The problem is - i have Linestring object on layer with ol.interaction.Modify.

All works great except one thing - it is impossible to delete last 2 vertex of Linestring (i understand why - minimum length of Linestring - 2 vertex, but i need to delete all Linestring in such case).

I can capture event of start modifying and finish modifying, but i can't understand - it was delete operation or not.

May be exists normal solution except modifying code of ОpenLayers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be able to provide some example code? It's quite difficult to understand what you are doing here.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, of cause (sorry - i had to do it early)  https://jsfiddle.net/oj2vs1dj/9/ This is example, which made 5 points Linestring on map, you can single click on each vertex to delete it, but last 2 points can't be deleted.

Comment: The modify interaction is written to be quite general. It is lacking in the fact that it won't actually tell you which features were modified, but only gives you the collection that was selected. (it also has a [problem](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6716) related to Snap, but that's probably not the issue here). The best you can hope for is to override Modify#removePoint, and do something. However, this wraps the before/after modify events and most of the internals of Modify are private and not accessible. Might have to write your own.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I thought about that. It's will be quite easy, if exists two additional event "add plot" and "remove plot". I think, i can leave a feature request at openlayers...

Comment: Is possible to create a sample Jsfiddle or anywhere.. where we can reproduce the same error or see whatever you have tried so far ?